# ship in alien invasion game won't move

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to create the alien invasion game from python crash course. But I edited the code, especially in settings.py that controls the window size and color and added a bit of code in the alien_invasion.py. I only edited the ship.py so it could run with the modified files. And now I did everything the book told me to but I can't move the ship.

alien_invasion.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
            if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                self.width = pygame.display.get_surface().get_width()
                self.height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_height()
                self.settings.display = pygame.display.set_mode((int(self.width), int(self.height)), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                if self.settings.R == 'default':
                    self.rgb_color = (59, 61, 151)
                else:
                    self.rgb_color = (int(self.settings.R), int(self.settings.G), int(self.settings.B))
                self.settings.display.fill(self.rgb_color)
                self.ship = Ship(self)

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

ship.py:

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.display = ai_game.settings.display
        self.display_rect = ai_game.settings.display.get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Space_ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.display_rect.midbottom

        self.moving_right = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += 1

    def blitme(self):
        self.display.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

settings.py:

```
import pygame
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        loop = True
        while loop is True:
            print(f"Set Window Size(Type 'default' to use default 1920*1080, type 'full' to use full screen)")
            self.screenX = input()
            if self.screenX == 'default':
                self.screen_size = (1920, 1080)
                self.display_mode = 'Window'
                loop = False
            elif self.screenX == 'full':
                self.display_mode = 'Full'
                loop = False
            elif int(self.screenX) == int:
                print("X")
                self.screenY = input()
                self.screen_size = (int(self.screenX), int(self.screenY))
                self.display_mode = 'Window'
                loop = False
            else:
                print("You either type a integer, 'default' or 'full'")
        loop = True
        while loop is True:
            self.R = input("\nSet RGB Color(type 'default' to use default color)"
                           "\nR: ")
            if self.R == 'default':
                self.R = 59
                self.G = 61
                self.B = 151
                loop = False
            elif int(self.R) is int:
                self.G = input("G: ")
                self.B = input("B: ")
                loop = False
            else:
                print ("Type an integer or 'default'")
            self.rgb_color = (int(self.R), int(self.G), int(self.B))
        if self.display_mode == 'Window':
            self.display = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
        elif self.display_mode == 'Full':
            self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.display.fill(self.rgb_color)
import pygame
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        loop = True
        while loop is True:
            print(f"Set Window Size(Type 'default' to use default 1920*1080, type 'full' to use full screen)")
            self.screenX = input()
            if self.screenX == 'default':
                self.screen_size = (1920, 1080)
                self.display_mode = 'Window'
                loop = False
            elif self.screenX == 'full':
                self.display_mode = 'Full'
                loop = False
            elif int(self.screenX) == int:
                print("X")
                self.screenY = input()
                self.screen_size = (int(self.screenX), int(self.screenY))
                self.display_mode = 'Window'
                loop = False
            else:
                print("You either type a integer, 'default' or 'full'")
        loop = True
        while loop is True:
            self.R = input("\nSet RGB Color(type 'default' to use default color)"
                           "\nR: ")
            if self.R == 'default':
                self.R = 59
                self.G = 61
                self.B = 151
                loop = False
            elif int(self.R) is int:
                self.G = input("G: ")
                self.B = input("B: ")
                loop = False
            else:
                print ("Type an integer or 'default'")
            self.rgb_color = (int(self.R), int(self.G), int(self.B))
        if self.display_mode == 'Window':
            self.display = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
        elif self.display_mode == 'Full':
            self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.display.fill(self.rgb_color)
```

Comment: That can't really be your code, because you can't have `for event` followed by `elif`.

Comment: you should get error message in console when you run it - because you have mistake in `for event`. And this can be your problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah, I copy pasted it, there was code in front of it, I forgot to edit the code in the question. still, can you tell me what's the problem with my code except that? I literally did everything the book told me to do.

Comment: No, please add the missing code.  Otherwise, we can't comment.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok, I've just went and pasted all the code in there

Comment: `elif int(self.screenX) == int:` does not do what you think it does.  What are you expecting there?  Same with `if int(self.R) is int:`.  I suspect you wanted `elif self.screenX.isdigit():` there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that causes your problem is this:

```
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:   # <<<
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
```

Look what happens when you press the right-arrow.  That will be a keydown event, so you'll take the first `elif` clause, but that ONLY checks for the escape key.  If it's not the escape key, it does nothing, and it skips the rest of the elifs.

The solution is to delete the `elif` line I have marked.  Once you know it is a keydown event, check all the keys you're interested in.

And be sure to fix the `== int` and `is int` problems I mentioned above, and replace them with `.isdigit()` calls.